# How to generate unique Id for use with Mongodb?(Java)

Tags: java, mongodb, jakarta-ee, quarkus

I am using MongoDB Panache. I want to get auto generated Id (not ObjectId) after persisting new Document. How can I do it?

Comment: `ObjectId` is the auto generated ID provided by MongoDB. So I strongly advise to use them.

Comment: Looking for something like this https://data-flair.training/blogs/mongodb-auto-increment-sequence/ ?

Comment: What do you mean (not ObjectId)?  Why does ObjectId not meet your needs?  What are your requirements?

Comment: See this post: [Generating Globally Unique Identifiers for Use with MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb). The post discusses creating custom unique identifiers (in addition to the default ObjectId).